# Синхронизация работы двух slideToggle?

Tags: jquery

Есть выпадающее меню. Под ним должен ездить контент. Я сделал дополнительный блок menuMargin, который показывается когда меню открыто. Проблемы начинаются когда я кликаю на другую ссылку меню.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qz55hhde/2)

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  $(function () {
      var links = $('.menu a.parrent');
      links.click(function (e) {
          links.not(this).siblings('ul').slideUp(300);
          $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle(300);
            $('.menuMargin').slideToggle(300);
      });
  });
});
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь впихать всю логику в несколько toggle, а логики вообще-то много: открытие из закрытого состояния, переключение на другое меню, закрытие открытого меню. Просто разделите всю логику явно:

```
$(function() {
  var links = $('.menu a.parrent');
  var openMenu = null;
  links.click(function() {
    if (openMenu == this) { // закрыть меню
      links.siblings('ul').slideUp(300);
      $('.menuMargin').slideUp(300);
      openMenu = null;
    }
    else if (openMenu != null) { // переключить меню
      links.not(this).siblings('ul').slideUp(300);
      $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown(300);
      $('.menuMargin').slideDown(300);
      openMenu = this;
    }
    else { // открыть меню
      $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown(300);
      $('.menuMargin').slideDown(300);
      openMenu = this;
    }
  });
});
```